# Accessing JPA Data with REST, POSTing using CURL store permanently

Tags: spring, rest, curl, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Following the tutorial [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/), I have successfully made my application with data on my localhost:8080/driver, pretty much exactly like the tutorial.

My question is the part where is says create a new element using curl:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{  "firstName" : "Frodo",  "lastName" : "Baggins" }' http://localhost:8080/people
```

It does work for me, shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV3h8.png):

However, when I rerun the server, the data disappears. How do I store/POST data permanently to my database created with Spring?

Alternatively, can I store an existing and separate JSON data from the client into there? Besides the Batch Service way.

I feel like this a very basic question, but I cannot find the answer on the Spring Docs, I think I'm not searching for the right words.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide is using an `H2` in-memory database. hence, every time you re-run your app, that app's data will be gone:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> How do I store/POST data permanently to my database created with
>   Spring?

Check out [spring boot's doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-sql) for that.